# what kind of regression model I should use for integer and bounded dependent variable?

Tags: regression, negative-binomial-distribution

I am trying to model the rating of a product (that takes integer values between 0 and 10) using some other predictors. 
Can I use negative binomial regression? The data is over-dispersed toward higher ratings but I am not sure whether negbin works for bounded counts.

Answer (score 2):

Negative binomial data is a model for count data, I think that would make it difficult to interpret the results. Two sensible approaches would be either fitting a [proportional odds model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit) or computing a "[top-box](http://marketresearch.about.com/od/market.research.surveys/qt/Surveys-Research-Creating-Delayed-Branching-Survey-Questions.htm)" indicator of 9, 10 responses and model that using logistic regression or other binary data analysis method.

Comment: +1, I think the proportional odds model (or something similar like ordered probit) is the default for problems like this.